# Disable displaying FETCH_HEAD in TortoiseGit

Tags: git, branch, tortoisegit

I'm new to Git. I don't recall issuing `git fetch` ever (always use `git pull`), but the thing is, that at "some point" one of my repos started to show `FETCH_HEAD` "branch", when I use use `TortoiseGit > Switch/Checkout`. It appears only in TortoiseGit, I neither see it in Netbeans, nor I can't list it with `git branch`. I want to get rid of it. How to do this?

Is there any option or trick to stop TortoiseGit from showing this in `Switch/Checkout` dialog box?

I've browsed all TortoiseGit' Settings dialog's panel and found nothing, that could help I've searched the Internet and also ended up with nothing. I heard that many GUIs have option to disable showing extra labels, like this one. Is TortoiseGit among them or do I have to get used to this extra "branch"?

Comment: `FETCH_HEAD` is not a real branch, it's a special label left behind by `git fetch`.  Apparently in these GUIs there's some tickybox you can check or uncheck to stop it from showing you special labels that you don't care about.  (I generally hate GUIs so I have no idea where the box hides).

Comment: Thanks! I have reformulated the question, as it become much easier after your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TortoiseGit will support this starting with 1.8.13.1.

This can be changed in TortoiseGit settings on the Dialogs 2 page.

Comment: Thanks for an information. However, because of this (discussed here) and many other issues in TortoiseGit, I dropped using it (in favor of Git for Windows and command-line approach) over a year ago. So, I'm accepting your answer without even chance to test this new feature.